# Monaco Editor 0.20 doesn't respond to element size change (without window size change)

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

I'm updating a relatively old React application that uses Bootstrap and the Monaco Editor. The editor is placed inside an Overlay (in an Overylay trigger). Even though the editor is configured with `automaticLayout: true`. In the old Monaco version (0.17), triggering the overlay caused the editor's layout to be recalculated - as it should.

I have updated to Monaco Editor 0.20, and now triggering the overlay does not cause the editor's layout to be recalculated. It remained very small. Automatic layout does work - if I change the browser's window size.

A work around was to set `automaticLayout: false`, and call `editor.layout` a few times a second - which is what Monaco should do according to its documentation. What has changed?